# Check if element has two classes

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I have 2 possible divs.

```
<div class='a b'></div>
```

and

```
<div class='c d'></div>
```

Is there a way to check if div element has 2 classes a and b?

I use Ruby, Capybara and XPath for selecting elements but css is fine if it could solve problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This css selector should work in capybara:

```
page.has_css?('div.a.b')
```

which will match

`<div class="a b">` but not `<div class="a">`

Comment: yes but its uglier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881044/how-to-get-html-elements-with-multiple-css-classes

Answer (score 6):

You can do this :

```
page.should have_css('div.a.b')
```

If you don't use rspec, it's this :

```
page.has_css?('div.a.b')
```

Comment: This requires Rspec, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. You can use `page.has_css?('div.a.b')` if you don't want RSpec.

Answer (score 2):

**XPath solution**:

**Use**:

```
div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' a ')
  and
    contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' b ')
   ]
```

This selects any `div` child of the context node, whose `class` attribute contains both the classes `"a"` and `"b"`.

**If it is required that the `class` attribute of any selected `div` contains exactly (only) these two classes and no other classes, use**:

```
div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' a ')
  and
    contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' b ')
  and
    string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 3
   ]
```